# Why is this assumption needed in Cauchy's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am studying complex analysis and **Cauchy's theorem** states:

> Suppose that a function $f$ is analytic in a simply connected domain $D$ and that $f'$ is continuous in $D$. Then for every simple closed contour $C$ in $D$, $\oint_C f(z)dz = 0$

Next after this theorem the book presents  **Cauchy-Goursat theorem** which states that we don't actually need  $f'$ to be continuous as assumption.

**My question:** If it is given that function $f$ is analytic in a domain $D$ doesn't it mean that function $f$ is infinitely differentiable in that domain? Then we know that $f'$ is differentiable and so we know that $f'$ must be continuous. What I don't understand is why it is a big deal removing the assumption of continuous derivative if it is already implied by analyticity of the function. What am I missing?

Comment: in one variable there are differentiable functions in an interval with a derivative that is not continuous; also there are degrees of differentiability like $C^1,C^{\infty}$, analytic etc; the main point about functions in a plane domain is that no such distinctions exist, so in other words, if the function is just complex differentiable in an open set in the plane, it is automatically analytic there which is if you want the best possible kind of differentiability, so while analyticity always implies differentiability, the reverse is a very strong rigidity property of functions in the plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version I know of this theorem states only the hypothesis that $f$ has a (complex) derivative, except possibly at a finite number of points.

Furthermore, the proof that, if $f$ is holomorphic, it is infinitely differentiable depends on this theorem.